# PlotRange values changed by AspectRatio and PlotLabels

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting, labeling, visualization

I'm running into a strange issue with ListPlot.

I'm trying to plot some data with particular values for PlotRange, PlotLabels, and AspectRatio. However, if I enforce the desired values for PlotLabels and AspectRatio (as in plt1 below), Mathematica 12.2 is changing the output's PlotRange. Yet, if I enforce only one of PlotLabels or AspectRatio (as in plt2 or plt3 below), it returns the correct PlotRange. Is there a way to simultaneously specify all three correctly?

I've attached a minimal working example.

```
data = Table[{x, 1}, {x, -2., 2.}];
plt1 = ListPlot[
  data
  , PlotRange -> {{-2., 2.}, {0., Sqrt[2.]}}
  , PlotLabels -> "PlotLabels and AspectRatio"
  , AspectRatio -> .353553
  ]
```

[image: PlotRange is incorrect]

```
plt2 = 
 ListPlot[
  data
  , PlotRange -> {{-2., 2.}, {0., Sqrt[2.]}}
  , PlotLabels -> "PlotLabels"
  ]
```

[image: The PlotRange is correct]

```
plt3 = 
 ListPlot[
  data
  , PlotRange -> {{-2., 2.}, {0., Sqrt[2.]}}
  , AspectRatio -> .353553
  , PlotLabel -> "AspectRatio"
  ]
```

[image: The PlotRange is correct]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlotRangePadding` is the option you are not controlling.  Set it to `None` to get the control you seek.

```
data = Table[{x, 1}, {x, -2., 2.}];
plt1 = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-2., 2.}, {0., Sqrt[2.]}}, 
  PlotLabels -> "PlotLabels and AspectRatio", AspectRatio -> .353553, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Set to larger values if desired (see docs).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!